# MySQL: select all parents AND date of most recent child AND date of any future child

Tags: mysql

I have an existing query which gets me the parent record plus the greatest date from any child records.  The child records are calls made. I have now been asked to show the date of the most recent "past" call and the date of any future "scheduled" calls.

Here is the query I am using now:

```
SELECT doctor.*, contact.date_scheduled
FROM doctor 
LEFT JOIN contact ON doctor.doctorID = contact.doctorID 
AND date_scheduled = (SELECT MAX(date_scheduled) FROM contact WHERE doctor.doctorID = contact.doctorID)
ORDER BY date_scheduled DESC
```

Can someone please show me how to modify this query to get the two dates as I have described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT d.*,
       max(case when c.date_scheduled < now() then c.date_scheduled end) as MostRecentCall,
       group_concat(case when c.date_scheduled >= now() then c.date_scheduled end) as FutureCalls
FROM doctor d left join
     contact c
     on d.doctorID =  c.doctorID
GROUP BY d.doctorId;
```

This will put future call dates in a list, separated by commas.

EDIT:

If you only want doctors that have calls scheduled in the future, then use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT d.*,
       max(case when c.date_scheduled < now() then c.date_scheduled end) as MostRecentCall,
       group_concat(case when c.date_scheduled >= now() then c.date_scheduled end) as FutureCalls
FROM doctor d left join
     contact c
     on d.doctorID =  c.doctorID
GROUP BY d.doctorId
HAVING sum(c.date_scheduled >= now()) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I like this.  Can you please help me with one small tweak?  This only selects parents where there IS a future call scheduled.  I need to get all parents even if there is no call scheduled in the future.

Comment: Gordon, I just changed the group_concat on the future calls query to a max.....I am OK assuming that there will only ever be one call scheduled in the future.

Comment: Actually...I apologize.  My edit did not fix the problem of the query only returning parent records who have a child (contact) record scheduled in the future.  I am still struggling with that.  Can you please help?

Comment: Gordon, I truly appreciate your help with this and apologize that I have not been clear....I think this should do it...I need ALL doctor records, whether or not they have any call records.  If there are past call records, I need the date of the most recent one AND if there is a future scheduled call, I need it's date too.  If you could help me get to that....this will be a good day.  Thanks.

Comment: @CameronS . . . That is what the original query should be doing.  It was missing the `group by d.DoctorID`, so that might have been a problem.

Comment: YES...that was it.  Thank you very much.  Will mark your answer.